# Double Sigma combinations: $\sum_{j=0}^{11}\sum_{i=j}^{11}\binom ij$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Find the sum.
$$\sum_{j=0}^{11}\sum_{i=j}^{11}{i \choose j}.$$

I am getting the answer as $4095$ although the answer is given as $4092$.

Comment: $4095$ is correct for the mentioned sum.

Comment: [WolframAlpha agrees with you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5BBinomial%5Bi,j%5D,%7Bi,j,11%7D%5D,%7Bj,0,11%7D%5D). So it's probably a typo, albeit an unfortunate one.

Answer (score 16):

Say you want to choose a non-empty subset of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,11\}$, which has $12$ members.

Since the subset to be chosen is non-empty, it has a largest member.  Let $j$ be the number of members other than the largest member. There can be $11$ other members or $0$ other members or anything in between. Call the largest member $i$, and observe that $i$ must be at least $j$, since it can be equal to $j$ if, but only if, the $j$ non-largest members are $0,1,2,\ldots,j-1.$ The largest member is in the set $\{j,j+1,j+2,\ldots,11\}.$ Thus the total number of possibilities is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{11} \sum_{i=j}^{11} \Big( \text{number of ways to choose $j$ members from $\{0,1,2,\ldots,i-1\}$ } \Big).
$$
$$
= \sum_{j=0}^{11} \sum_{i=j}^{11} \binom i j.
$$

But the total number of **non-empty** subsets of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,11\}$ is $2^{12}-1 = 4095.$

Comment: Nicely done! (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer : Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure! I appreciate your abilities to derive a proper interpretation from combinatorial identities and I often try to grasp the ideas.

Answer (score 15):

> Your answer is correct, since
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^{11}\sum_{i=j}^{11}\binom{i}{j}&=\sum_{0\leq j\leq i\leq 11}\binom{i}{j}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{11}\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{i}{j}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{11}2^i\\
> &=\frac{2^{12}-1}{2-1}\\
> &=4095
> \end{align*}

Comment: I up-voted this answer. But I also posted a more combinatorial rather than algebraic answer. $\qquad$

Comment: And, of course, there is nothing special about 11. If you replace it by $n$, the sum becomes $2^{n+1}-1$.